# Is there a word for "the use of opposite expressions" similar to "comparison"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, literature, literary-device, literary-english

Is there a word as a use of language when the writer uses an opposite / bad example to make the correct / other ones particularly stand out?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give us an example?

Comment: hmmm, I'm not sure is this an example but "The oval classroom tables, set in a semi-circle, ensure that there is no such thing as a back row like traditional schools."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/apagogic

apagogic (not comparable):

(rhetoric) Proving indirectly, by showing the impossibility or absurdity of the contrary.

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/apagoge

apagoge (countable and uncountable, plural apagoges):

(logic) An indirect argument which proves a thing by showing the impossibility or absurdity of the contrary.

Disclaimer: literally nobody has ever heard of these terms

When used as a debate tactic you would refer to it as "reductio ad absurdum"

Comment: I see, thank you